# PyCharm project path different from interactive session path

Tags: python-3.x, path, pycharm

When running an interactive session, PyCharm thinks of `os.getcwd()` as my project's directory. However, when I run my script from the command line, PyCharm thinks of `os.getcwd()` as the directory of the script.

Is there a good workaround for this? Here is what I tried and did not like:

- going to Run/Edit Configurations and changing the working directory manually. I did not like this solution, because I will have to do it for every script that I run.
- having one line in my code that "fixes" the path for the purposes of interactive sessions and commenting it out before running from command line. This works, but feels wrong.

Is there a way to do this or is it just the way it is supposed to be? Maybe I shouldn't be trying to run random scripts within my project?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Clarification**:

- By "interactive session" I mean being able to run each line individually in a Python/IPython Console
- By "running from command line" I mean creating a script my_script.py and running `python path_to_myscript/my_script.py` (I actually press the Run button at PyCharm, but I think it's the same).

**Other facts that might prove worth mentioning**:

- I have created a PyCharm project. This contains (among other things) the package Graphs, which contains the module Graph and some .txt files. When I do something within my Graph module (e.g. read a graph from a file), I like to test that things worked as expected. I do this by running a selection of lines (interactively). To read a .txt file, I have to go (using `os.path.join()`) from the current working directory (the project directory, `...\\project_name`) to the module's directory `...\\project_name\\Graphs`, where the file is located. However, when I run the whole script via the command line, the command reading the .txt file raises an Error, complaining that no file was found. By looking on the name of the file that was not found, I see that the full file name is something like this:
  `...\\project_name\\Graphs\\Graphs\\graph1.txt`
  It seems that this time the current working directory is `...\\project_name\\Graphs\\`, and my `os.path.join()` command actually spoils it.

Comment: below two answers although provide insights to the problem but not the solution. have you figured out a solution giving same path from the Shell and the Interactive session?

Comment: No, not really. If I had absolutely had to do something about it, it would be to include a line testing how the script is called and setting the working directory accordingly (i.e. if run by the command line then no change, else if run interactively, set it to be the project's directory). As I say above, this works, but it feels like an amateurish way to solve the problem. Glad to see someone else shares my problem though! :)

Answer (score 1):

I user various methods in my python scripts.

> set the working directory as first step of your code using `os.chdir(some_existing_path)`

This would mean all your other paths should be referenced to this, as you hard set the path. You just need to make sure it works from any location and your specifically in your IDE. Obviously, another `os.chdir()` would change the working directory and `os.getcwd()` would return the new working directory

> set the working directory to `__file__` by using `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

This is actually what I use most, as it is quite reliable, and then I reference all further paths or file operations to this. Or you can simply refer to as `os.path.dirname(__file__)` in your code without actually changing the working directory

> get the working directory using `os.getcwd()`

And reference all path and file operations to this, knowing it will change based on how the script is launched. **Note: do NOT assume that this returns the location of your script, it returns the working directory of the shell !!**

[EDIT based on new information]

> By "interactive session" I mean being able to run each line
>   individually in a Python/IPython Console

By running interactively line-by-line in a Python console, the `__file__` is not defined, afterall: you are not *executing a file*. Hence you cannot use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` you will have to use something like `os.chdir(some_known_existing_dir)` to reference a path. As a programmer you need to be very aware of working directory and changes to this, your code should reflect that.

> By "running from command line" I mean creating a script my_script.py
>   and running python path_to_myscript/my_script.py (I actually press the
>   Run button at PyCharm, but I think it's the same).

This, both executing a `.py` from command line as well as running in your IDE, will populate the `__file__`, hence you can use `os.path.dirname(__file__)`

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Please forgive my noob-ness and elaborate on a couple of points:
 
 1) When I try `os.chdir(__file__)` (interactively), I get the error message: `'__file__' not defined`. Do I need to do something more than that?
 
 2) I did not understand the note in bold. I assume it is very important though :) Please elaborate.

Feel free to post citations instead of writing down the explanations yourself.

Comment: I made an slight error, and have now corrected this to `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` in the above answer. This probably does not help you with your problem though. I am not familiar with PyCharm, so it could be that `__file__` is not defined. I would recommend reading up on PyCharm

Comment: Fair point. I am afraid that `os.chdir(custom_path)` is not what I want, since the package should be portable. From what I can observe, it seems that `__file__` is not defined in the interactive mode, but is defined when running from the command line (probably not a PyCharm issue). Since I would like to run both times, this will not work, either. Could you please explain what the working directory of a shell is?

Comment: Please update your post, to clarify "running from command line" and "interactive mode" specify **exactly** how you run your script, so we can help you further...

Comment: Thanks for the update. It offers valuable insight on python's path setting methods, as well as the `__file__` variable. Its only issue is that the cure is equally bad to the illness (i.e. manually setting a path is just as bad, since portability is lost). This is also the reason I created a project instead of having random .py scripts. I assume that PyCharm probably has something that fixes this problem, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I am purposely adding another answer to this post, in regards the following:

> **Other facts that might prove worth mentioning:**
>
> I have created a PyCharm project. This contains (among other things)
>   the package Graphs, which contains the module Graph and some .txt
>   files. When I do something within my Graph module (e.g. read a graph
>   from a file), I like to test that things worked as expected. I do this
>   by running a selection of lines (interactively). To read a .txt file,
>   I have to go (using os.path.join()) from the current working directory
>   (the project directory, ...\project_name) to the module's directory
>   ...\project_name\Graphs, where the file is located. However, when I
>   run the whole script via the command line, the command reading the
>   .txt file raises an Error, complaining that no file was found. By
>   looking on the name of the file that was not found, I see that the
>   full file name is something like this:
>   ...\project_name\Graphs\Graphs\graph1.txt It seems that this time
>   the current working directory is ...\project_name\Graphs\, and my
>   os.path.join() command actually spoils it.

I strongly believe that if a python script takes input from any file, that the author of the script needs to cater for this in the script.

What I mean is you as the author need to make sure you know the following regardless of how your script is executed:

- What is the working directory
- What is the script directory

These two you have no control over when you hand off your script to others, or run it on other peoples machines. The working directory is dependent on how the script is launched. It seems that you run on Windows, so here is an example:

```
C:\> c:\python\python your_script.py
```

The working directory is now `C:\` if `your_script.py` is in `C:\`

```
C:\some_dir\another_dir\> c:\python\python.exe c:\your_script_dir\your_script.py
```

The working directory is now `C:\some_dir\another_dir`

And the above example may even give different results if the `SYSTEM PATH` variable is set to the path of the location of `your_script.py`

You need to ensure that your script works even if the user(s) of your script are placing this in various locations on their machines. Some people (and I don't know why) tend to put everything on the Desktop. You need to ensure your script can cope with this, including any spaces in the path name.

Furthermore, if your script is taking input from a file, the you as the author need to ensure that you can cope with changes in working directory, and changes of script directory. There are a few things you may consider:

- Have your script input from a known (static) directory, something like `C:\python_input\`
- Have your script input from a known (configurable) directory, use `ConfigParser`, you can search here on stackoverflow on many [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+use+ConfigParser+in+python)
- Have your script input from a known directory related to the location of the script (using `os.path.dirname(__file__)`)
- any other method you may employ to ensure your script can get to the input

Ultimately this is all in your control, and you need to code to ensure it is working.

HTH,
Edwin.

Comment: Firstly, my sincere gratitude for posting not one, but two extensive answers, I honestly appreciate this. To comment on the answer, a project is supposed to be a cohesive unit. It does not really matter what its path is, as long as I know the relative paths within the project (which I do). Having said that, my question refers to python/PyCharm interpreting **the same command** `os.getcwd()` **in two different ways**, depending on whether I am running interactively or from the command line and what I could do to avoid this while keeping portability at hand.